# ObservableCollection binded to DataGrid cell updated event

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

**CODE** (related to problem)

```
 <DataGrid      Grid.Row="1"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding WatchList}" />
public static WatchListData<Quote> watchList;
watchList=new WatchListData <Quote>();
public WatchListData <Quote> WatchList
    {
        get { return watchList; }
        set
        {
            watchList = value;
        }
    }

public class WatchListData<Quote> : ObservableCollection<Quote>
{
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        MessageBox.Show(e.Action.ToString());
    }
}

 public class Quote : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _symbol;
    private double _last;

    public string Symbol
    {
        get { return _symbol; }
        set
        {
            _symbol = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Symbol");
        }
    }

    public double Last
    {
        get { return _last; }
        set
        {
            _last = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Last");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

**PROBLEM**
I have WPF DataGrid binded to ObservableCollection. When user clicks to datagrid, type text and press enter or click to other row or window he adds new line and I need to get this line and execute some code. Also I need to get this event when user changes value in the cell. I'm trying to use ***override void OnCollectionChanged*** but it fires when user **start** to type in new cell (right after he press first key, but not when he finished) and not firing when user changes text in existing cell. Only "Add" action fires to early, no "Replace" action fires at all. Any solutions possible?

Comment: have you tried to subscribe Quote.PropertyChanged int he WatchListData class?

Comment: @sexta13, Yes I tried    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        }       Set breakpoint there in debug mode. It fires only when user start editing cell, but not fires when user finished editing cell or changed existing cell

Comment: not that. Where are you doing the fill of WatchListData <Quote> WatchList? Imagine Quote q = new Quote; q.PropertyChanged+=NAME_YOU_WANT. If you have Quote props binded to view it should work

Comment: @sexta13. That's something. But it not fires when user delete existing row. Also when user changing value in existing cell this event cant's say what. Wait a minute, I can use PropertyChanging event to get what will be changed. But they also not firing when user delete a row.

Comment: when the user deletes a row, the only thing you can do is the collectionchanged event. At least is what I think...can't you RaiseProperyChanged on this public WatchListData <Quote> WatchList ?